# Why does parsing a locale date string result in an invalid date?

Tags: javascript, date

Can someone explain why the following snippets result in an invalid date object?

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleString())
// or
Date.parse(new Date().toLocaleString())
```

Comment: It's because `new Date` accepts a string in the IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp format, or ISO8601 format, it does not support random local datestrings, like those created by `toLocaleString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expressly permitted by the [ES5 specification's definition of `Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) (emphasis mine):

> ...all of the following expressions should produce the same numeric value in that implementation, if all the properties referenced have their initial values:
>
> ```
> x.valueOf()
> Date.parse(x.toString())
> Date.parse(x.toUTCString())
> Date.parse(x.toISOString())
> ```
>
> However, the expression
>
> ```
> Date.parse(x.toLocaleString())
> ```
>
> **is not required to produce the same Number value** as the preceding three expressions and, in general, **the value produced by `Date.parse` is implementation-dependent when given any String value that does not conform to the Date Time String Format** ([15.9.1.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)) and that could not be produced in that implementation by the `toString` or `toUTCString` method.

Since `toLocaleString` is not required to produce a string conformant to the Date Time String Format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, it is allowable for its output not to be parsed correctly by `Date.parse`.

Comment: Doesn't _"Permit"_ imply something explicit like _"Output from `Date.toString()` doesn't have to be parse-able by `Date.parse`"_? I'd just call the in / outputs formats incompatible...

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with the phrasing in your quoted sentence: "*`d.toLocalString()` doesn't have to be parseable by `Date.parse`*." That is what I meant to express with the phrase, "*it is allowable for [`toLocaleString`'s] output not to be parsed correctly by `Date.parse`.*" I disagree (pedantically) with the term "incompatible," which suggests to me a negative assertion about `parse`'s ability to parse `toLocaleString`'s output. Since both `parse` and `toLocalString` have implementation-defined behaviors, their compatibility is implementation-defined (so it has spec-*undefined* compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

[`new Date().toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) returns the current date in a format [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) can't parse, resulting in unexpected dates.

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, all the info required to parse that is available, after all, it's possible to generate that string...
Also, there's no 'parse exact' where a format could be provided, so my question is, if it's possible at all without a third party lib?

Comment: That's a new question. Sure, it's probably possible, but since you're trying to parse a locale-dependent string, it's going to a _big_ hassle to do so. You'd be better off using a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: You should probably never create a date from a  `toLocaleString`. It can be very ambiguous, consider for example Sweden which is the only country in the world which uses YYYY/MM/DD in practice. If we tried to use a swedish date (1970/08/01) as input you might end up with the 8th of January instead of the first of August.

Comment: @max in C#, you can do DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture). This option is missing from javascript