# Native method to inverse Date.toLocaleString convertion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, locale, date-parsing

We have date converted to `locale string`. For example:

```
x = (new Date()).toLocaleString()
```

and x has value

```
"20.05.2018, 10:21:37"
```

How to process this string to `Date` object.

I was tried

```
new Date(x)
Invalid Date
```

and

```
Date.parse(x)
NaN
```

It is possible and simple to do without external libraries like `moment.js`?

Comment: [Why does parsing a locale date string result in an invalid date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988868/why-does-parsing-a-locale-date-string-result-in-an-invalid-date)

Comment: You don't need to parse again the stringified date, just store date in a variable `date`and use it: `date = new Date(); dateStr = date.toLocaleString();`

Comment: What implementation produces that output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse it on your own.

```js
const date = "20.05.2018, 10:21:37";
const [first, second] = date.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
const [day, month, year] = first.split('.');
const [hours, minutes, seconds] = second.split(':');

const newDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
console.log(newDate);
```

Or using regex

```js
const date = "20.05.2018, 10:21:37";
const m = /^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}), (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/.exec(date);
const newDate = new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1], m[4], m[5], m[6]);
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: The split can be simplified using `dateString.split(/\D+/)` to get all the numeric values in one go, so `let [d,m,y,h,M,s] = "20.05.2018, 10:21:37".split(/\D+/); new Date(y,m-1,d,h,M,s)`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the format of the date without knowing it beforehand.

```
// should default to toLocaleDateString() format
var formatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat()
// I suggest formatting the timestamp used in
// Go date formatting functions to be able to 
// extract the full scope of format rules
var dateFormat = formatter.formatToParts(new Date(1136239445999))
```

On my machine `dateFormat` yields

```
[
    {type: "month", value: "1"},
    {type: "literal", value: "/"},
    {type: "day", value: "3"},
    {type: "literal", value: "/"},
    {type: "year", value: "2006"},
]
```

By iterating over this array it should be feasible to parse a string into parts and then fill them in a `Date` object.